# why i get "no attirubute error" when i try to call python function from c++

Tags: python, c++

Hi' i follow this [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#compiling) to call the python function from a c++ code.

This is embeddedPython.cpp

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc;
    PyObject *pArgs, *pValue;
    int i;

    if (argc < 3) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: call pythonfile funcname [args]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    Py_Initialize();
    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault(argv[1]);
    /* Error checking of pName left out */
    std::cout << pName << std::endl;
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);

    if (pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, argv[2]);
        /* pFunc is a new reference */
        // didn't add the all code 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And test.py

```
def multiply(a,b):
    print("Will compute", a, "times", b)
    c = 0
    for i in range(0, a):
        c = c + b
    return c
```

And finally CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(demo)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(demo embeddedPython.cpp)
target_link_libraries(demo ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

when I try to run the following command:

```
./demo test multiply 3 2
```

I get the following error.

```
AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'multiply'
Cannot find function "multiply"
```

What could be the problem? I think; I can access the file but the code can't find the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of your Python file is `test.py` but there is already a Python module `test` for regression tests (see Python documentation) which doesn't contain a multiply() function. Rename your python file to avoid collision with existing modules. The example in the tutorial uses `multiply.py` which works. I used `test1.py` which works too.